# Error: cannot access JobInstance in Spring batch 3.0.0

Tags: spring

We are trying to migrate spring batch version to 3.0.0. I have below code in my application .

```
 List<JobInstance> jobInstance = getJobExplorer().getJobInstances(job.getName(), 0, 1);

    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();

    JobExecution jobExecution = null;

    if (!jobInstance.isEmpty()) {
        jobParameters = jobInstance.get(0).getJobParameters();
```

When i tried to do the maven build using jdk1.8 and i got the below exception

error: cannot access JobInstance

Could let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance

Maven compilation error:

```
error: cannot access JobInstance

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals
```

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

Finally found that issue. This is because of getparameters removed from JobInstance class in spring batch 3.0.0 version.The method was moved to JobExecution class